# I am getting an error saying List Index out of range even though for me it looks like its within the list index

Tags: python, function, indexing, range

I'm very new to python. I was trying to write a code which has a function called 'pos' which takes in a list and check for positive numbers in the list and returns a new list containing only the positive numbers.

Please find the code below:

```
def pos(l1):
    p1=[]
    for ele in l1:
        if ele>0:
         p1.append(l1[ele])
    return p1

num = list(range(-5,50,2))
print(num)
val=pos(num)
print(val)
```

However I am getting an error saying the list index is out of range. Im not sure why im getting this error.

This is the o/p im getting:

### [-5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49]

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-7ff66d3dec65> in <module>
     10 num = list(range(-5,50,2))
     11 print(num)
---> 12 val=pos(num)
     13 print(val)

<ipython-input-49-7ff66d3dec65> in pos(l1)
      3     for ele in l1:
      4         if ele>0:
----> 5          p1.append(l1[ele])
      6     return p1
      7 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Can somebody please help?**

Also,when i remove the step size in the range function i get this o/p. However, its not returning only positive elements. Please find the code and o/p below.

```
def pos(l1):
    p1=[]
    for ele in l1:
        if ele>0:
         p1.append(l1[ele])
    return p1

# rnum=range(-5,10,2)
# print(list(rnum)
num = list(range(-5,50,2))
print(num)
val=pos(num)
print(val)
```

[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

[-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Please help

Thank you

Comment: You're calling `l1[ele]` where `ele` is defined as `for ele in l1`. That means ele is the element, not the index. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: It should be `p1.append(ele)` - you iterate on the items, not on the indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are iterating over the values of the list (and not using an index), `p1.append(l1[ele])` is trying to access the index of whatever the value of `ele` is. For example if `l1 = [-1,0,20,3]`, on iteration 3 `l1[ele] --> l1[20]` which is  not what we want

```
def pos(l1):
    p1=[]
    for ele in l1:
        if ele > 0:
         p1.append(ele)
    return p1

num = list(range(-5,50,2))
print(num)
val=pos(num)
print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

'ele' in your case is element of the array. NOT its index. You are getting index error because instead of trying to access element of the array by its index you access element of the array using its element as an index.

Try changing
for ele in range(l1):
with
for ele in range(len(l1)):

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `ele` is already elements in list:

```
def pos(l1):
    p1=[]
    for ele in l1:
        if ele>0:
            p1.append(ele)

    return p1

num = list(range(-5,50,2))
print(num)
val=pos(num)
print(val)
```

Also man your function is an overkill :-( so just use a list comprehension:

```
def pos(l1):
    return [x for x in l1 if x > 0]

num = list(range(-5,50,2))
print(num)
val=pos(num)
print(val)
```

Comment: Thank you Wasif.Still getting a hang of python. Not that expert to use list comprehension now.
But can i ask u a qn?
The list comprehension which u showed will be returning very first +ve value in the list instead of all the +ve ones?

```
def pos(l1):
    p1=[]
    p1.append(x for x in l1 if x>0)
#     for ele in l1:
#         if ele>0:
#          p1.append(ele)
    return p1

num = list(range(-5,50))
print(num)
val=pos(num)
print(val)
```
I changed it but getting ``` [<generator object pos.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000022382E9B8C8> ``` as o/p